# What is the car's sound?

Tags: noise

If you press the gas pedal, the engine makes louder sound, which I am guessing is the sound of fuel explosion, so why if you are in neutral the sound gets louder than you are engaged to the transmission though it is the same amount of fuel igniting both cases??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not quite! 
When you are in gear your transmission consumes the torque produced by the engine resulting in lower RPM 
But when you are in neutral there is nothing holding the engine from releasing the potential energy thus higher revs = more fuel burnt =more sound

Comment: Just to completely understand, the roaring sound coming from the engine is from the fuel ignition? Or is it something else like piston going up or down or pumps and so? Or are they both together?

Comment: Typically they include valve sound. Explosion sound , crankshaft sound . with the combusting sound being most prominent to notice.  If car is totally idle you may also hear valve tappet noise

Comment: So if you're just pressing the gas pedal in neutral it makes a loud noise because it is rotating at high rom but when at the same level of gas pedal but you pressed the clutch and engaged a gear the sound gets quiet because the car consumes the power output and it will become louder as the car speeds up? Is that true?

Comment: Exactly! You get the point